# Python exception handling with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, nagios

I am new to Python and I am trying to write a nagios script which uses selenium to log into a webapp and print out some information.  As of now the script works as expected but I would like it to alert the system if it fails to retrieve the website.  Here is what I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from selenium import webdriver

url = '<main web site>'
systemInformation = '<sys information site>'
logout = '<log out link>'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('<path to phantomjs for headless operation>')
login_username = '<username>'
login_password = '<password>'

try:
    browser.get(url)
    username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
    password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")

    username.send_keys(login_username)
    password.send_keys(login_password)

    link = browser.find_element_by_name('loginbutton')
    link.click()

    browser.get(systemInformation)

    print "OK: Web Application is Running"
    for element in browser.find_elements_by_name('SystemReportsForm'):
        print element.text

    browser.get(logout)
    browser.quit()
    sys.exit(0)
except:
    print "WARNING: Web Application is Down!"
    sys.exit(2)
```

I would expect if that first section fails it would then go to the except section, however the script is printing out both the try and except even though there is an exit.  I'm sure it's something simple I am missing.

Thank's in advance

**Update**

This is how I ended up resolving this issue, thanks for the help

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, urllib2
from selenium import webdriver

url = '<log in url>'
systemInformation = '<sys info url>'
logout = '<logout url>'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('<phantomjs location for headless browser>')
login_username = '<user>'
login_password = '<password>'

def login(login_url,status_url):
    browser.get(login_url)
    username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
    password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")

    username.send_keys(login_username)
    password.send_keys(login_password)

    link = browser.find_element_by_name('loginbutton')
    link.click()

    browser.get(status_url)

    if browser.title == 'Log In':
        print "WARNING: Site up but Failed to login!"
        browser.get(logout)
        browser.quit()
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print "OK: Everything Looks Good"
        for element in browser.find_elements_by_name('SystemReportsForm'):
            print element.text

        browser.get(logout)
        browser.quit()
        sys.exit(0)

req = urllib2.Request(url)

try:
    urllib2.urlopen(req)
    login(url,systemInformation)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print('CRITICAL: Site Appears to be Down!')
    browser.get(logout)
    browser.quit()
    sys.exit(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sys.exit([status])` raising `SystemExit(status)` exception that's why the except clause is executed

> Exit the interpreter by raising SystemExit(status). If the status is
>   omitted or None, it defaults to zero (i.e., success). If the status is
>   an integer, it will be used as the system exit status. If it is
>   another kind of object, it will be printed and the system exit status
>   will be one (i.e., failure).

Remove `sys.exit(0)` inside `try`
(if you shown the complete version of the script)